# Flutter Firestore countdown to date, seconds not matching

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a strange issue that I don't seem to be able to figure out. In short, I store Timestamp in Firestore, retrieve them and show them in a super basic Flutter application that basically just counts down to those dates as you can see in the screenshot (ignore the fact that those dates are in the past, those things don't matter right now). The values are printed like this: Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds.
[image: Example image]

As you can see everything is kinda working as expected, except for the seconds. Both dates are counting down to 00:00:00, so the seconds should be the same and this is what I don't understand. Below is the code I'm using to build the countdown label.

```
class CountdownLabel extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime startDate;

  const CountdownLabel({
    super.key,
    required this.startDate,
  });

  @override
  CountdownLabelState createState() => CountdownLabelState();
}

class CountdownLabelState extends State<CountdownLabel> {
  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Duration get durationUntilStart {
    Duration duration = widget.startDate.difference(DateTime.now());
    return duration >= duration ? duration : const Duration(seconds: 0);
  }

  Widget _durationInHoursMinSecsWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        componentWidget(durationUntilStart.inDays.toString()),
        hoursMinSecSeparator,
        componentWidget(durationUntilStart.inHours.remainder(24).toString()),
        hoursMinSecSeparator,
        componentWidget(durationUntilStart.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString()),
        hoursMinSecSeparator,
        componentWidget(durationUntilStart.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString())
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget get hoursMinSecSeparator => Text(
        ':',
      );

  Widget componentWidget(String text) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          text,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        _durationInHoursMinSecsWidget(context),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Retrieving the Timestamps from Firestore is just through a basic service with a pagelimit of 20. Don't think this can have anything to do with it since I only have 10 records currently so all the records get loaded at the same time.

Any help in which direction to search for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that this is because you use a separate call t `DateTime.now()` for each countdown timer. If multiple `CountdownLabelState` widgets are rendered at slightly different times (as rendering each widget takes some time), they'll have slightly different `now` values.

If that is a problem for your use-case, consider have a single `now` value in the state of a parent widget - and passing that into each `CountdownLabelState` widget.

Comment: Hi, is calling a different `DateTime.now()` can cause also this difference in actual time when using them in methods as examples, or this behaviour can be thrown only when trying to render widgets based on them?

Comment: `DateTime.now()` returns the current time whenever it is called. If you want to use the same "now" for all widgets, you need to call `DateTime.now()` only once across all of them.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, thank you for your reply. I understand what you're saying but I'm not really sure how to implement it. I tried adding  `final DateTime currentDate;` in `CountdownLabel`, and then in my event_item widget I call `CountdownLabel(startDate: event.startDate.toDate(), currentDate: DateTime.now())` but now the timers are not counting down anymore and there is still a difference in seconds.

Comment: If you want a single value for "now" you should have a single call to `DateTime.now()` in your code. That's all my answer explains. If that makes sense and you have a single `DateTime.now()` call in your code, but it still doesn't work - it might be best to post a new question for that. But read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before doing so please, as it'll be important to have such a minimal repro.

Comment: I just want to give an update here: if you insert a Datetime through the Firestore interface itself, the milliseconds are not 000. This is what caused the difference in time. If it inserts one record with '31/12/2022 00:00:00:123' and another one with '31/12/2023 00:00:00:895', then of course if you count down to those dates, the first one will run ahead of the other... No clue why it does this though. But since I will only insert through the app I can make sure those milliseconds are always 000.

Comment: * in combination with the comment from Frank of course.